# NDK-link a library into another library"Cannot load library: link_image[1966]: 1765 could not load needed library..."

Tags: android, android-ndk

first of all I want to tell you what I want to do. I have a .h-file and a .c-file with usual C-Code in it with which I created a shared library with the Android NDK. So now I have a .so-file which is called libtry.so. Furthermore, I want to use native code in my Android Eclipse project. So I created .java-file with the class "Counter" and the content

```
public native static int Number(int n);
```

and

```
static
{
   System.loadLibrary("test");
}
```

Then I create a C-header file from the .java-file with the javah tool.

Afterwards I create a C-sourcefile for the C-Headerfile in which I implement the native code.

Then I create a shared library with those two files with `LOCAL_MODULE := test`, so that the file will be named `libtest.so` . But the point is, that I want to link the shared library libtry.so, which I created at the beginning, to this shared library.

So in the Android.mk-file of libtest.so I put `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L/root/Android/Samples/Test/libs/ -ltry` .

Actually this works because I can compile this Android.mk-file with ndk-build.

But now in my Eclipse project, if I want to use the library libtest.so it does not work. I mean If I create an object of the Class "Counter" in which the library libtest.so is loaded,

I get the `error: "Cannot load library: link_image[1966]: 1752 could not load needed library 'libtry.so' for 'libtest.so'"` .

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using your so file for a different project or the one in which you have your C code

Comment: For the same project. Actually I want to explain it again for some more details. The .so file libtry.so contains functions which have to be used by libtest.so. So what I did was to link the libtry.so to libtest.so in the Android.mk of libtest.so, like shown in my first comment. I can compile with the ndk-buid. But I cannot use the libtest.so in my Eclipse proejct because of the error shown in the title of this topic.

Comment: My answer with this link was deleted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593987/android-ndk-linking/10615769#10615769
In response to your reply, yes, the steps in the link shows how to build a 3rd libtry.so with just c source. In my case it was a physics library which we have to use in many of our games. So we considered building a separate lib for future use.

Comment: Thank you codetiger for your link. I will give it a try and tell you how it worked.

Comment: Did you solve this problem ? i'm getting the same error

Answer (score 4):

You are linking a library to a library. In the Java code they must be loaded explicitly in reverse order e.g.

```
static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("dependencylib"); // try 
        System.loadLibrary("mainlib");       // test
    }
```

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058898/loading-shared-libs-that-depend-on-other-shared-libs)