# Android link .so for command line executable?

Tags: android, c, command-line, shared-libraries

I am developing a cross-platform library, and am trying to test on Android. I have compiled my library with ndk-build, and am trying to compile and run a command-line test fixture we have for the library.

I use `adb push` to put the test fixture and .so in `/data/local/tmp` and `chmod` both to 777.

Then I use `adb shell` to run the test, but get the following error

```
shell@android:/data/local/tmp $ ./mytest
./mytest
link_image[1936]:  7289 could not load needed library 'libtconfig.so' for './mytest' (load_library[1091]: Library 'libtconfig.so' not found)CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE
```

Both `mytest` executable and `libtconfig.so` are in the same directory. I would have assumed it looks in "." directory first?

Comment: I think I might be encountering this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11085509/571778

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I can add the path `/data/local/tmp` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and it will work, however when using `adb shell` commands in a script, each "`adb shell`" is a new instance, so `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is reset

Comment: Yes, this is all exactly as expected.  As a general unixism, the current directory is usually not on either the executable or library search paths, because having it there lets someone set traps for other users by leaving malicious code with the same name as system commands/libraries in directories which users might visit.