# How to include versioned *.so file into apk using Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, shared-libraries, apk, native

I trying to build android application with some precompiled native libraries:
**liba.so** and **libb.so.1.2.3**

Libraries are placed into jniLibs subdirectory.
After building APK file, only **liba.so** included into it, but not **libb.so.1.2.3**.

Result is predictable. Application crashes at start.

What to do with build scripts to include all files from jniLibs into APK?

Comment: were you able to solve your problem? i need solution too.

Answer (score 4):

Due to the native library regex `^.+\\.so$` being used in the [Android Gradle plugin](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/builder/src/main/java/com/android/builder/internal/packaging/Packager.java#58), it is impossible to include anything other than `.so` files using the `jniLibs` folder. And even if you were to somehow add the library to the APK, the dynamic loader on Android is [very limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11085509/207861) and will most likely not be able to load them.

Your best bet is to remove the version altogether by renaming the library and changing its internal `soname` *before* linking against it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't develop for Android anymore, so I can't test this, but I know Gradle and this might work for you. Looking at the [Android DSL docs](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceDirectorySet.html), you might be able to change the filtering on the `jniLibs` folder:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.filter.include("**/*")
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: I have tried this, it gives an error: **Cannot set readonly property: filter for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceDirectorySet**

Comment: Can you try setting the whole jniLibs? I can try to test it maybe tomorrow, if I can install the Android SDK. But it would be something like `jniLibs { filter = '' srcDir = '' }` etc (all properties from the docs).

Comment: So the filter is a PatternSet. I've updated my answer. This compiles (I tried it with Android plugin) but I can't deploy the app as I don't have any .so to try.

Comment: @kostashv I wonder if you have found your answer, it's an interesting problem ;)

Comment: I have tried code from your updated answer. It compiles, but versioned lib still not packed into apk. Also I have tried to **exclude** not versioned libs from apk and that didn't work to.

Answer (score -1):

Just add the jniLibs folder in app/src/main and it will include the .so file in the apk.

/app/src/main/armeabi/*.so files