# External library and JNI with Android: dlopen failed: library "libcrypto.so.1.1" not found, even with SONAME set correctly

Tags: android, apk, cross-compiling

I've cross-compiled OpenSSL for Android (`x86` and `arm`). I added the `.so` files (respectively: `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so`) to the generated `.apk` file by using a `jniLibs` through `build.gradle`. I've checked, and the `.so` files are properly packed in the generated `.apk`.

Now, the `.so` files are properly named:

```
$ objdump -p libssl.so | grep SONAME
  SONAME               libssl.so.1.1
$ objdump -p libcrypto.so | grep SONAME
  SONAME               libcrypto.so.1.1
```

And yet, when the code is executed, I get the following error: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libcrypto.so.1.1" not found`.

I mentioned in the title that I'm using JNI, because the issue actually comes when one of the JNI module is created.

The structure of my project is as follow:

- I have a `JNILibrary` Android Studio project, whose goal is to generate an Android library (`.aar` file). It has 2 `.java` classes: `AgentWrapper.java`, and `ClientWrapper.java`, which both expose native methods. The `CMakeLists.txt` file compiles the C (JNI) code, and the generated `.so` files (`libagent.so` and `libclient.so`) are bundled in the final `.aar`.
- This `JNILibrary` Android Studio project also contains a `LibraryWrapper.java` class ; it contains abstraction methods that handle the native methods implemented in JNI (accessible through `AgentWrapper.java` and `ClientWrapper.java`).
- The C code of `AgentWrapper.java` uses the OpenSSL library. It's dependant of both `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so`, which are both bundled in the generated `.aar`.

With that done, I create another Android Studio project, `JNILibraryTestApk`. I import the previously generated `.aar` library, and use it inside my `MainActivity`: `LibraryWrapper.TestMethod();`. This method calls a `Client` method, then a `Agent` method. When it reaches the `Agent` method, and tries to load the `libcryto.so` file... The application crashes and I am greeted by the usual error message.

Note: if I remove the part that calls a method from the `Agent` library (which is the one using `libcrypto.so.1.1`), the application runs fine, which proves that the issue is probably only coming from the `libcrypto.so[.1.1]` file missing/not found.

If anyone can help me with this, I'd be really grateful, I'm starting to lose my mind on this!

Cheers

Comment: I am also facing same issue ....Did you resolve it

Comment: @manjunathkallannavar The library is most probably compiled for the wrong architecture. You can check the architecture of the `.so` by using the `file` linux software.

Comment: thank you for the reply .I checked all libraries compiled against right architectures with file command

Comment: Possible solution is that Android does not support versioned .sos so you need to build an unversioned version or find one. That is why only the unversioned .sos become included.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if the file is called "libcrypto.so", you should request it using:

System.loadLibrary("crypto");

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on information such as:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55080634/4959635

Android's Gradle does not support versioned .sos so you should aim to use and build unversioned libraries.