# Packaging external .so files into Android .apk files using Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Recently, I ported my existing Android project from an ancient Gradle version to Gradle 6.6 and Android Studio's Gradle plugin 4.0.1. This project uses an external native library (.so file) that gets used in the Java code via JNI. This .so library has a dependency on `libc++_shared.so` because it is written in C++.

I realized that if I just copy the .so file into the corresponding platform folder (`arm64-v8a`, `armeabi-v7a`, `x86`, `x86_64`) within the `jniLibs` Gradle packages it "properly" into my .apk file.

By "properly" I mean that it automatically adds `libc++_shared.so`, which my library has a dependency on, as well as my own library to the .apk file. In addition, if I additionally set `jniDebuggable` to `true` in the `build.gradle` file it will also add the `gdbserver` library which is required to be able to attach the native code debugger.

Now, this is *exactly* what I want. The problem is that I cannot find any documentation that describes this behavior. The best source I could find is [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#jniLibs) but it does not mention anything about dependencies being packaged automatically. So, I don't know whether that is an officially supported way of doing things.

I suspect that there is a part of Android's Gradle based build process that automatically analyzes the files in the `jniLibs` folder and acts accordingly. It would be great to know a bit more to be aware what is really going on.

Does anyone have a reference that confirms my above observations or know which Gradle task (or whatever) accomplishes this? It would also be good to know in which Android Gradle plugin version this behavior was introduced.

**Edit:**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55080634) answer to another SO question led me to the Android source file [https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/builder/src/main/java/com/android/builder/internal/packaging/Packager.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/builder/src/main/java/com/android/builder/internal/packaging/Packager.java#401)
which seems to be the code that packages the .so files and `gdbserver` into the .apk file. But I have no explanation why `libc++_shared.so` gets packaged as well.

Comment: so let's see if I understand your code is working you just searching some doc that states that this is the correct way doing it so ?

Comment: @PedroAGSantos Yes, correct. Everything is working as it should. But I discovered that I can make it work that way just by trying things out. Nothing I could find anywhere in the Android documentation actually states that it can be done that way. So, essentially, I just want to make sure that I can rely on this mechanism.